# No title & content with bootstrap.ui tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to make tabs with [Angular bootstrap.ui Tabs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/Tabs). Static tabs work, but dynamic don't show title and content. Below my code:

My JS:

```
(function (angular) {
  angular.module('numeter', ['ui.bootstrap']).
    controller('configurationMainTabCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.maintabs = [
        { title:"Users", content:"Test", url:"/user" },
        { title:"View", content:"", url:"/view" },
      ];
    }]);
}(angular));
```

My HTML:

```
...
<div ng-controller="configurationMainTabCtrl">
 <tabset maintabs>
  <tab ng-repeat="maintab in maintabs">
   <tab-heading>{{maintab.title}}</tab-heading>
   {{maintab.content}}
  </tab>
 </tabset>
</div>
...
```

This code show me empty tabs selectable with empty content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses.
It was a noob mistake. I use Django and `{{...}}` are evaluated by Django template system. I add [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-verbatim) tag to escape angular part and it works.

Comment: You can save yourself doing that multiple times by using $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("{[").endSymbol("]}"); or whatever symbols you like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include all your code, I'm not sure if this was the problem, but in future it'd be mighty helpful if you linked to a plunker or fiddle. That way, we can see the code in action, and it's also easier to fork that with the solution. (Plus I find plunkers handy for narrowing down things to just the exact code I'm working on, which helps me troubleshoot.)

Here's a plunker with your code, edited: http://plnkr.co/edit/u80OhmN7YqYRytFE7kG5?p=preview

When using your setup, the only error I got was that it couldn't see your controller as a function, which means it's not picking up on the ng-app. As soon as I add ng-app="app" to the body tag, everything started working. Since I've only got the code you posted, I'm not sure, but that might've been one problem.

The other possible culprit might be these two lines:

```
<tabset maintabs>
    <tab ng-repeat="maintab in maintabs">
```

change them to this:

```
<tabset>
    <div ng-repeat="maintab in maintabs">
```

and then things should be behave. Otherwise you've got ng-repeat on the tab directive, when the directive expects just one tab per, well, tab. Put the  part inside the ng-repeat, not alongside it, I mean.

Comment: I'vz already made a Plunker but it works... Thx for your advises.

Comment: So does it work in the plunker but not inside your full app? Edited my answer to highlight the two critical lines.

Comment: Yeah, it works in plunker, and doesn't work in my app without `<tabset maintabs>`.

Comment: Could you edit your original question & add a link to that plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its relevant to your case, but I had the same issue in a different scenario. If you are using `ng-include` like this `<div ng-include="'mytemplate'" ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>`, then there is a scoping [problem](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5067) somewhere between 1.1.6 and 1.2.2 which might explains why you might not be seeing maintabs.

Comment: Thanks for show me that issue, but the trouble came from bad Angular/Django usecase.